# What's eth0 used for in docker host machine

Tags: networking, docker

I'm using Docker on Windows. When I ssh to a docker host machine(local VM) and type `ifconfig`, normally we get something like this:

```
docker@master:~$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:82:A3:2D:FB  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:E8:A3:F6  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee8:a3f6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39044 (38.1 KiB)  TX bytes:39544 (38.6 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:83:CF:41  
          inet addr:192.168.99.101  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe83:cf41/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29987 (29.2 KiB)  TX bytes:32525 (31.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2752 (2.6 KiB)  TX bytes:2752 (2.6 KiB)
```

I know that `docker0` is the bridge network created by Docker, `eth1` is the interface connects to the outer world, `lo` is the loopback interface, my question is what's `eth0` here used for?

Comment: Isn't eth0 the main IP for you local VM? Usually eth0 on Linux is the main network interface like Windows has Ethernet, Virtual Host Only, the same Linux has eth0 as the network interface for your host

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu, I understand your meaning. Do you agree what I said in my own Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the point. When I come to the VirtualBox Network Settings, I found there're 2 network cards, and the first one using NAT with port forwarding.

```
Name:ssh | Host Port:53289 | Guest Port:22
```

So I thought the `eth0` is used for ssh connection by docker client. That's why there's no such an interface in a normal Linux OS(rather than this Boot2Docker local VM).

Different ideas are welcome!